# How to minimize ionic2 built app.bundle.js file size if I only need run it on a browser?

Tags: ionic2

How to minimize `ionic2` built `app.bundle.js` file size if I only need run it on a browser?
Can I drop some `css`, `font` and `js` files?

Comment: Why would you use Ionic if you only need to run it on a browser?

Comment: Try to run: ionic build --release

Comment: ionic build --release reduced my file size from about 5mb to 2.2mb. This was then reduced to 387kb of transfer with gzip compression enabled on my server